# Blocking multiple AJAX requests on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have problem with multiple AJAX requests. For example there is a button when user clicks on it an AJAX request is made and a record is entered into the database. However, if an user clicks on the button multiple times really fast then multiple AJAX requests are made simultaneously which causes same record to be entered into the database twice. I tried `async: false` or making button inactive still it is happening.

**JavaScript**

```
var myObject = {
    demoButton : function(thisIdentity) {
    "use strict";
    var myObj = this;
    $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var trigger = $(this);
        trigger.addClass('inactive_icon');
        var param = trigger.attr("rel");
        var item = param.split("_");
        var section = trigger.attr("data-section");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mod/check_login.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data.job == 1)
                {
                    $.post('mod/button_processing.php',{ id : item[0], job : item[1] }, function(data) {
                        var new_id = item[0] + '_' + data.job + '_' + item[2];
                        if (data.job != item[1]) {
                            if (data.job === 0) {
                                trigger.attr("rel", new_id);
                                if(section == 'postOpen')
                                {
                                    trigger.css("color", "#677077");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    trigger.css("color", "white");
                                }
                                myObject.updateCount(item[0]);
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data : { aid : item[2], type : 1, pid : item[0] },
                                    url: "mod/mark_notifications.php"
                                });                                    
                            } 
                            else if(data.job === 1) 
                            {
                                trigger.attr("rel", new_id);
                                trigger.css("color", "red");
                                myObject.updateCount(item[0]);
                                $.post('mod/add_notification.php',{ pid : item[0], paId : item[2], type : 1 }, function(data) {
                                    if(data.nid != false)
                                    {
                                        var action = 'like';
                                        myObj.conn.sendMsg(item[2], data.nid, action);
                                    }
                                }, 'json');
                            }
                            else if(data.job === 2)
                            {
                                mscAlert({
                                  title: 'Error',
                                  subtitle: 'Try some time later.',
                                  okText: 'Close',
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }, 'json');                        
                    trigger.removeClass('inactive_icon');
                }
                else if(data.job == 0)
                {
                    var param = {'c': 2};   
                    $('.element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
                        content: 'ajax',
                        contentContainer: '.content',
                        loadUrl: 'mod/filler.php',
                        loadData: param,
                        modalColor: '#fff',
                        positionStyle: 'fixed',
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
}, //other functions 
}
$(function() { myObject.likeButton(".like"); }
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="like" //other attributes>Like</button>
```

> Is there any way to block simultaneous AJAX requests if same request
>   is already working?

Any suggestions or references would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server and network go fast, and your client process a "slow" double-click on the button which launches the ajax call, then you will still have a double-call.

You could force a timeout before the user can make the same ajax call twice. Set a condition around your ajax call :

```
// ...
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.data('timeout') != undefined) {
    $this.data('timeout', true);
    setTimeout(function() { $this.removeData('timeout'); }, 1000);
    $.ajax({
    // ...
```

Which this the user will be abble to click a second time in one second only. If you want him to never be abble to click again, then remove the setTimeout. Or give him more time with 2000 ms or more. Or again you could removeData('timeout') from another event in your form (onchange() on inputs ?) when your user will be allowed to send data for a second time. All depends in what you exactly want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a check to the beginning of your click listener will solve this:

```
var myObject = {
    demoButton : function(thisIdentity) {
    "use strict";
    var myObj = this;
    $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (window.inAjax) {
            return false;
        }
        window.inAjax = true;
        var trigger = $(this);
        trigger.addClass('inactive_icon');
        var param = trigger.attr("rel");
        var item = param.split("_");
        var section = trigger.attr("data-section");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mod/check_login.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data.job == 1)
                {
                    $.post('mod/button_processing.php',{ id : item[0], job : item[1] }, function(data) {
                        var new_id = item[0] + '_' + data.job + '_' + item[2];
                        if (data.job != item[1]) {
                            if (data.job === 0) {
                                trigger.attr("rel", new_id);
                                if(section == 'postOpen')
                                {
                                    trigger.css("color", "#677077");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    trigger.css("color", "white");
                                }
                                myObject.updateCount(item[0]);
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data : { aid : item[2], type : 1, pid : item[0] },
                                    url: "mod/mark_notifications.php"
                                });                                    
                            } 
                            else if(data.job === 1) 
                            {
                                trigger.attr("rel", new_id);
                                trigger.css("color", "red");
                                myObject.updateCount(item[0]);
                                $.post('mod/add_notification.php',{ pid : item[0], paId : item[2], type : 1 }, function(data) {
                                    if(data.nid != false)
                                    {
                                        var action = 'like';
                                        myObj.conn.sendMsg(item[2], data.nid, action);
                                    }
                                }, 'json');
                            }
                            else if(data.job === 2)
                            {
                                mscAlert({
                                  title: 'Error',
                                  subtitle: 'Try some time later.',
                                  okText: 'Close',
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        window.inAjax = false;
                    }, 'json');                        
                    trigger.removeClass('inactive_icon');
                }
                else if(data.job == 0)
                {
                    var param = {'c': 2};   
                    $('.element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
                        content: 'ajax',
                        contentContainer: '.content',
                        loadUrl: 'mod/filler.php',
                        loadData: param,
                        modalColor: '#fff',
                        positionStyle: 'fixed',
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
}, //other functions 
}
$(function() { myObject.likeButton(".like"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the button to be disabled immediately on click would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with @Stuart s answer.
You can also do below hacks-
when user clicks on button 
1. rename button name to "`please wait..`" and remove onclick(if any).
2. if you are just submitting form without any validation (like `onsubmit='return validation()'`) then point no 1 will do same trick.